# Spark 3 is failing when I try to execute a simple query

Tags: sql, crash, spark3

I have this table on Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`raw_sales` (
`combustivel` STRING,
`regiao` STRING,
`estado` STRING,
`jan` STRING,
`fev` STRING,
`mar` STRING,
`abr` STRING,
`mai` STRING,
`jun` STRING,
`jul` STRING,
`ago` STRING,
`set` STRING,
`out` STRING,
`nov` STRING,
`dez` STRING,
`total` STRING,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP,
`ano` STRING)
USING orc
LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:9000/jobs/etl/tables/raw_sales.orc'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime' = '1601322056',
  'ORC.COMPRESS' = 'SNAPPY')
```

There is data on table, but when I try this query at bellow:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mydb.raw_sales WHERE ano = '2000' AND combustivel like '%GASOLINA%'").show()
```

It's crashing!

```sh
>>> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mydb.raw_sales WHERE ano = 2000 AND combustivel like '%GASOLINA%'").show()                                                                         [164/3679]
20/09/28 19:25:30 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 61.0 (TID 133)                      
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number                      
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.castLiteralValue(OrcFilters.scala:163)                              
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.buildLeafSearchArgument(OrcFilters.scala:235)                               
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFiltersHelper$1(OrcFilters.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.$anonfun$convertibleFilters$4(OrcFilters.scala:137)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFilters(OrcFilters.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.createFilter(OrcFilters.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$4(OrcFileFormat.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$4$adapted(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:491)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20/09/28 19:25:30 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 61.0 (TID 133, 639773a482b8, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.l
ang.Number
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.castLiteralValue(OrcFilters.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.buildLeafSearchArgument(OrcFilters.scala:235)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFiltersHelper$1(OrcFilters.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.$anonfun$convertibleFilters$4(OrcFilters.scala:137)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFilters(OrcFilters.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.createFilter(OrcFilters.scala:75)                                                                             [112/3679]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$4(OrcFileFormat.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$4$adapted(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:491)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20/09/28 19:25:30 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 61.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 440, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/opt/spark/current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o122.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 61.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 61.0 (TID 133, 639773a482b8, executor dr
iver): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.castLiteralValue(OrcFilters.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.buildLeafSearchArgument(OrcFilters.scala:235)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFiltersHelper$1(OrcFilters.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.$anonfun$convertibleFilters$4(OrcFilters.scala:137)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFilters(OrcFilters.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.createFilter(OrcFilters.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$4(OrcFileFormat.scala:189)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)                                                                                                                                        [59/3679]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)                                                    
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:491)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2120)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:467)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:420)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3627)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2697)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)                                                                                 [7/3679]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2697)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2904)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:337)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.castLiteralValue(OrcFilters.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.buildLeafSearchArgument(OrcFilters.scala:235)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFiltersHelper$1(OrcFilters.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.$anonfun$convertibleFilters$4(OrcFilters.scala:137)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.convertibleFilters(OrcFilters.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.createFilter(OrcFilters.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$4(OrcFileFormat.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$4$adapted(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:491)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
```

However, this query at bellow works!

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mydb.raw_sales WHERE ano = 2000").show()
```

And this works too!

```
spark.sql("SELECT combustivel FROM mydb.raw_sales WHERE combustivel like '%GASOLINA C%'  ").show()
```

My environment

- Hadoop 2.10.0
- Hive 2.3.7
- Tez 0.9.2
- Spark 3.0.1

The results is the same for pyspark and Scala.

I'm completely lost here! Maybe you can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the data of 'ano' field type to 'int'. Is not a ideal solution since even using 'cast' was not enough to resolve this issue! I have a good friend that is a monster on Spark that says that is possibly a bug on Spark. I'm not sure about that, but I would like that someone else corroborates this isue if possible!

Anyways, change data type to 'int' works!